# How can I check if a NPM package name is available?

Tags: npm

I used to check if a package name is available by opening `https://www.npmjs.com/package/<name>`.

That doesn’t work anymore as NPM checks for similar-name conflicts.

Is there a different way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `npm-name`

[`npm-name` @ npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-name) / [`npm-name` @ GitHub](https://github.com/sindresorhus/npm-name#readme)

> Check whether a package or organization name is available on npm

Install:

```
$ npm install npm-name
```

Usage:

```
const npmName = require('npm-name');
 
(async () => {
    // Check a package name
    console.log(await npmName('chalk'));
    //=> false
 
 
    // Check an organization name
    console.log(await npmName('@ava'));
    //=> false 
})();
```

2. `npm-name-cli`

[`npm-name-cli` @ npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-name-cli) / [`npm-name-cli` @ GitHub](https://github.com/sindresorhus/npm-name-cli#readme)

Install:

```
$ npm install --global npm-name-cli
```

Usage:

```
$ npm-name --help

  Usage
    $ npm-name <name> …

  Examples
    $ npm-name chalk
    ✖ chalk is unavailable
    $ npm-name abc123
    ⚠ abc123 is squatted
    $ npm-name unicorn-cake
    ✔ unicorn-cake is available
    $ npm-name @ava
    ✖ @ava is unavailable
    $ npm-name @abc123
    ✔ @abc123 is available
    $ npm-name @sindresorhus/is unicorn-cake
    ✖ @sindresorhus/is is unavailable
    ✔ unicorn-cake is available

  Exits with code 0 when all names are available or 2 when any names are taken
```

Comment: `npm-name-cli` didn't work for me. It told me that `rfui-react` is available but then when I ran `npm publish` I got `Package name too similar to existing package rf-ui-react; try renaming your package to '@adamzerner/rfui-react' and publishing with 'npm publish --access=public' instead`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in checking if an organization name is free, use the following URL:

https://npmjs.com/org/ORG_NAME_HERE

If you're getting a "404 Not Found" error, it means the name is free. Otherwise it is not.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this website to generate unused name

https://npmutil.com/

it is my open source project
[image]

only 7 `[consonants] [vowels] [consonants]` names left at the time of writing

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install npm-name
```

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-name

You could also refer to this: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry

Comment: Similar to this is https://remarkablemark.org/npm-package-name-checker/ . It works well, but keep an eye out for the error `Package name too similar to existing package` when doing `npm publish` as this tool will say it's available (which it is), but it's still not allowed by npmjs.com .